# WP add post_meta to custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Bogo to translate website. It says:"Translate posts and pages

You can translate posts and pages into the languages you have installed.

WordPress saves the contents of each post or page as usual, but Bogo adds ‘_locale’ post_meta data. The ‘_locale’ holds the language code of the post."

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bogo/#description

And I'm using Salient theme.

What is happening, Salient portfolio item does not work with BOGO language and once I open a portfolio item, 404 comes up.

I guess the part where I have to add "_locale" is in functions.php

```
 function portfolio_register() {  

     $portfolio_labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'taxonomy general name', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Portfolio Items', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'all_items' => __( 'Portfolio', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)
     );

     global $options;
     $custom_slug = null;       

     if(!empty($options['portfolio_rewrite_slug'])) $custom_slug = $options['portfolio_rewrite_slug'];

     $portolfio_menu_icon = (floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) >= "3.8") ? 'dashicons-art' : NECTAR_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY . 'assets/img/icons/portfolio.png';

     $args = array(
            'labels' => $portfolio_labels,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $custom_slug,'with_front' => false),
            'singular_label' => __('Project', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 9,
            'menu_icon' => $portolfio_menu_icon,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions')  
       );  

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );  
}  
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');
```

Can anyone help me adding locale?

Answer (score 0):

So, i think you just need to add "custom field" support to your custom post type.

It can be done by adding "custom-fields" to the "supports" parameter.

```
function portfolio_register() {  

     $portfolio_labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'taxonomy general name', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Portfolio Items', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'all_items' => __( 'Portfolio', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Portfolio Item', NECTAR_THEME_NAME)
     );

     global $options;
     $custom_slug = null;       

     if(!empty($options['portfolio_rewrite_slug'])) $custom_slug = $options['portfolio_rewrite_slug'];

     $portolfio_menu_icon = (floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) >= "3.8") ? 'dashicons-art' : NECTAR_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY . 'assets/img/icons/portfolio.png';

     $args = array(
            'labels' => $portfolio_labels,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $custom_slug,'with_front' => false),
            'singular_label' => __('Project', NECTAR_THEME_NAME),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 9,
            'menu_icon' => $portolfio_menu_icon,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions','custom-fields')  
       );  

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );  
}  
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');
```

Answer (score 0):

in functions.php

```html
add_filter('bogo_localizable_post_types', 'my_localizable_post_types', 10, 1);
function my_localizable_post_types($localizable) {
 $localizable[] = 'portfolio';
 return $localizable;
}
```

This adds translation options for custom post type.